# .NET Display Controller List To View

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm testing a method and I just want to display the list to the view. I know the list contains data as I was able to display the first result by a viewbag variable. How would I go about this without having it in a method which is the only other posts I can find? Thanks.

Error:

> The name 'foundEmails' does not exist in the current context

Controller action:

```
  public ActionResult EmailTest()
    {
        List<string> foundEmails = EmailScraper.Main();
        return View(foundEmails);

    }
```

View:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "View";
 }

 <h2>View</h2>

   @foreach(var item in foundEmails)
{
<p>@item</p>
}
```

Comment: `@foreach(var item in Model) { ... }` (and your view needs to include `@model IEnumerable<string>` at the top

Comment: Works perfect thank you :) however it displays this at the top? System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] IEnumberable

Comment: Sorry I do not understand your comment. What code is showing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for your question is to define `@model IEnumerable<string>` or `@model ICollection<string>` or `@model IList<string>` or even `@model List<string>` (I would personally pick the first option) at the top of the view file. Then you can run foreach loop on the Model object like this:

```
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
  <p>@item</p>
}
```

However, for more complex apps I would recommend creating a ViewModel class per view. Just imagine that you receive a requirement from the client and you need to implement some new business logic on given screen. It could mean that you will need 30 more fields to display on that screen. Of course, there are many ways to send a data from the controller to the view like for example using ViewBag object etc. but it can make your code a bit messy. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your view:

```
@model List<string>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "View";
 }

 <h2>View</h2>

   @foreach(var item in Model)
    {
     <p>@item</p>
    }
```